# Is there any WORDCHARS alternative in Bash?

Tags: mysql, bash, redis, readline, editline

Conculusion:

- No `WORDCHARS` alternative in Bash, where <kbd>C-w</kbd> ends can't be configured.
- `mysql` depends on `editline`, which is customizable with `~/.editrc`.
- `redis-cli` depends on `linenoise`, it deletes the whole word without considering `:`, `-`

---

In zsh, `WORDCHARS` controls the behavior of <kbd>C-w</kbd> when deleting a word. Is there any alternative in readline?

I've noticed recently the behavior of <kbd>C-w</kbd> in `mysql`/`redis-cli` differs that in Bash, although both of which depends on `readline`?

Take string `foo:bar` as an example, only `bar` is deleted by <kbd>C-w</kbd> in Bash. While in `mysql`/`redis-cli`, the whole word `foo:bar` is deleted.

How do I control this behavior?

Comment: Can't reproduce this in my `bash`. C-w deletes `foo:bar` as expected. Can you post the output of `bind -P | grep -w w`. Do you happen to have a space after `:`, i.e. `foo: bar`?

Comment: @Inian What's your bash version?

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.4.0(1), can you also confirm, no spaces exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two commands to do backward kill word :

```
backward-kill-word
unix-word-rubout
```

`backward-kill-word` deletes `bar`,
`unix-word-rubout` deletes `foo:bar`

Run following command to find out what `C-w` is bound to

```
bind -P | grep C-w
```

Seems bash doesn't have WORDCHARS as in zsh

Comment: vi-unix-word-rubout can be found on "\C-w". I tried to bind \C-w to `backward-kill-word` and `unix-word-rubout`. There's no difference in my test. Both of them only deletes only `bar` from `foo:bar`.

Comment: Have you checked on your `mysql/redis-cli`, what `C-w` is bound to ?

Comment: Thanks for your tips. I forgot to print the keybinding in these client. It proves a problem of redis-cli only. Maybe redis-cli doesn't depend on readline? I'll dig it deeper.